# Is there any one explain me how to exactly specify custom directory path in Plesk server?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to move moodle lms from local server to live server, I moved moodeldata to httpdocs and tired to figure out httpdocs directory path on shared Linux based Plesk server. I appreciate any one helps me!

I tried like this

```
$CFG->dataroot='\httpdocs\moodledata';
```

but the result is

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does
> not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Comment: As this is a linux environment, you can't use backslashes in paths. The backslash is an escape character. You should using a front slash as directory separator (`/`). For future reference, I'd advice you to only use front slashes in paths

Comment: I already used it many times but the result is the same

Comment: Well of course using a direct slash would indicate "starting from the root or the home folder". If moodledata is directly inside httpdocs I'd guess your folder would be `__DIR__ . '/moodledata'`

Comment: Thank you for you help and still am in trouble. I tried as your suggestion(__DIR__ .'moodledata') and also I changed to '/data/www/httpdocs/moodledata' but nothing solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help! And now I changed as

1. $CFG->dataroot  ='/data/www/example.com/moodledata'; then
2. I moved moodledata from httpdocs to home-directory and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, they should be forward slashes

```
$CFG->dataroot = '/moodledata';
```

Also, its a really bad idea to put the data root in a web directory (`httpdocs`) that's publicly available - put the data root in a directory that's outside of the web root

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

If you are migrating, then you probably need to backup the old data root too

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Moodle_migration#Copy_moodledata_from_the_old_server_to_the_new_server